# If $a_n$ is positive and decreasing, prove the alternating series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove:

> If $a_n$ is positive and decreasing, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n
> \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

My first instinct is to use the alternating series test (AST), but the inclusion of sequence $a_n$ has me a bit stumped. For the AST, I need to prove that the limit of $a_n=0$ and $a_n$ is decreasing, correct? I am given that it is decreasing and positive, so how can I use that to show that its limit equals $0$?

Would doing so show the series is convergent or is there another approach I should do?

Comment: Consider that sequence $a$ could be this: $1.1, 1.01, 1.001, 1.0001, \dots$

Comment: AST is definitely the right approach.

Comment: You're applying the AST to $a_n/n$, not just $a_n$ -- i.e., you need to show that $a_n/n \rightarrow 0$ and $a_n/n$ is a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You have $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \dots= -a_1 + \frac{a_2}{2}- \frac{a_3}{3}+-\dots$

You need to show three things for the AST to kick in. First that sequence $b_j$ is alternating in sign. Second that the sequence of absolute values $|b_j|$ is such that  $|b_{j+1}|\leq|b_j|$ always. Third that $b_j$ is a null sequence (that it converges to zero).

Since sequence $b$ is a simple transformation of sequence $a$, yes I think it would suffice to prove that the limit of $a_n$ is $0$ and is decreasing. BUT, you cannot assume that $a_n$ converges to zero.

Comment: Since the sequence $(a_n)$ is monotonic and bounded, it certainly converges. Therefore the sequence $(a_n/n)$ is a null sequence. The rest of the proof follows.